# Where would it be appropriate for me to ask about possible code optimizations?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Where do I want to ask questions about my completed, but slow code? I need advice on how to optimize a program I made in Python.

Comment: There may not be a need to ask a question if you apply general techniques, like [Mike Dunlavey's method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/378024).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Before posting, please read the [on-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page. You might also find [How to get the best value out of Code Review - Asking Questions](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2436/how-to-get-the-best-value-out-of-code-review-asking-questions) helpful.

If you don't feel your question would be on-topic there, then perhaps it would be helpful to take a look at [this answer to](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129632/341145) *[Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange sites do I post on?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129632/341145)*